# Login to Django web service using a secure connection

Tags: ios, django, web-services, security, password-protection

I have wrote a simple Django web service that provides an iOS app with JSON information containing download links.
I don't mind the JSON information to be clear text, but when the user logs in, I would like him to login with his username and password, then he would probably get some kind of key for future requests which I understand that can be sniffed out. For that first interaction, how could I protect the password and username from being clear text and sniffed?

I have decided I wanted to use a symmetric encryption to encrypt my password and have that key both on client and on server. (yes, I am aware that if someone goes to the trouble of binary hacking my app and sniffing packets from a customer he would be able to get the password in clear text, it's just not a likely concern).

I would like to use some kind of encryption that I can easily do in iOS and than decrypt in my django server. anyone has a suggestion on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encrypt the communication between your django server and the client then you can use secure HTTP rather than plain old HTTP. This is done outside django, and is configured at the web server level. For example, if your django app is ran by a WSGI server like gunicorn or uWSGI which in return is handled by nginx (this is a common setup) then you would configure your nginx server to accept only secure HTTP requests and forward any standard http request to https. This way you can ensure that everything the client sends to the server is encrypted on the browser prior to sending. Similar setup is done with Apache, though I personally have never used Apache with django.

Comment: I think setting up Gunicorn and nginx + buying a SSL and have the host support it is a bit much for my needs, my web service is completely open, its not that high risk, just that sending password plain text is bad habit, especially if my users might use the same password for other things.

Comment: I don't see any other viable option. Any encryption you will add on the client side will be visible to anyone to mimic. I am not aware of other solutions besides SSL. I saw that GoDaddy sell SSL certificates for 6$. They probably won't get verified as fast but it might be enough for your simple needs.

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP feels that HTTPS is not a viable option a modification of CHAP [Challenge-Handshake Authentication Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-Handshake_Authentication_Protocol) for the initial key creation might be an option.